# Pinsker-type inequality for moments?

Tags: distributions, moments, kullback-leibler

Let $f_1$, $f_2$ be two discrete probability distributions. By [Pinsker's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality), the [Kullback-Leibler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) divergence $D(f_1||f_2)$ sets an upper bound on the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between the two distributions, and thus on the difference between the probabilities that $f_1$, $f_2$ can assign to the same *event*.

Is there a similar result for *moments* instead of events? That is, given a measure of dissimilarity between $f_1$ and $f_2$ (which could be $D(f_1||f_2)$ or some other type of divergence), is there a bound on how much different $\mathrm E_1[X]$ and $\mathrm E_2[X]$ can be? Here $\mathrm E_1$ and $\mathrm E_2$ denote expectation with respect to $f_1$ and $f_2$. Or more generally, is there a bound on $\mathrm E_1[g(X)]-\mathrm E_2[g(X)]$, where $g$ is a function?

Comment: I doubt it; consider a t-distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu \to 1$ (from above) compared to one with $\eta = 1$.  The dissimilarity will go to zero for any non-moment-based dissimilarity measure, but there is no bound on the difference between expectations as the expectation at $\eta = 1$ is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a Pareto distribution with lower bound $x_m = 1$:  $p(x;\alpha) = \alpha / x^{1 + \alpha}$, with mean $\alpha / (\alpha - 1)$.  The K-L divergence of this distribution from a Pareto distribution with $\alpha = 1$ (and therefore infinite mean) is:

$$D(\cdot||\cdot) = \int_1^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{ x^{1 + \alpha}}{\alpha x^2}\right)\frac{1}{x^2}dx = \log(\alpha)(\alpha-1) \int_1^{\infty}\log(x)\frac{1}{x^2}dx$$

This integral clearly a) exists and b) $\to 0$ as $\alpha \to 1$ from above.  However, the difference in expectations between the two distributions remains at $\infty$, regardless of how small the K-L divergence is.  Consequently, the value of the K-L divergence cannot imply a bound (in general) on the difference(s) between moments.